# How do I get a list of installed printers?

Tags: java

I'm searching for a possibility to get a list of installed printers. I'm using JDK 1.6 with a Windows operating system. Does anyone know a solution?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Just wanted to add a little snippet:

```
import javax.print.*;

class Test {

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
        System.out.println("Number of print services: " + printServices.length);

        for (PrintService printer : printServices)
            System.out.println("Printer: " + printer.getName()); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used this myself, but maybe [`javax.print.PrintServiceLookup`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/PrintServiceLookup.html) contains what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Update for the newer Java packages

just modify:

```
import javax.print.PrintService;

import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
```