# Print a String to all printers connected to a system

Tags: java, printers

I am developing an application,When I press a print button a string of data is to be Printed by all the printers connected to the system.  When I browse sample codes,a string of data is printed by a default printer. I needed to be printed by all the printers.

Can we print a String of data to all the printers connected to a system?

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to get the list of installed printers and then send your string over.  Check out [How do I get a list of installed printers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410967/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-printers)

Comment: I want to send it to all the printers but the code detects only the printers connected to it.

Comment: Then chances are the printers are not setup properly or registered properly with the service. Can you post the lookup code?