# How to get Active connected printers in Java?

Tags: java, printing

I am a bit new in this topic. Actually I want list of Printers which are connected to my PC currently in Java. I referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410967/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-printers) for solving my problem. But the problem is, it is giving me all the printers whose drivers are installed in my PC (even if they are not connected right now).

How can I get list of Printers which are connected currently?

Comment: see here:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html

Comment: @rafiq : Thank you for your support. I didn't find how to get currently connected printers with this class. Can you please help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [PrinterStateReason](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/PrinterStateReason.html) class.