# Java Get only ZPL printers from system in Windows

Tags: java, zpl

Is there any way to get only the ZPL printers in the system in Java? I don't want to list printers which does not allow to print Zebra Commands.
Thanks.

Comment: Read the answers to [How do I get a list of installed printers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410967/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-printers) and see if you can modify the code to get Zebra printers.

Comment: Gilbert, I know how to get the list of printers, but I don't know how to check if the printer accept ZPL code or not... I didn't found the Zebra SDK for Java to see if there is any class which can be used to list only the ZPL printers. That's I asked, maybe someone did it! This is what I asked, if can I check somehow if the printer in the list accept ZPL code or not.

Comment: Don't you know which printers are Zebra printers?  Create a `List` of all the Zebra printers in your network, then compare your list to the printer list.

Comment: Gilbert, is not about me... it is about the user which uses the application. He see a combobox with some printers. If I don't filter the comobox with only the printer which can print the ZPL code for the label he/she can choose any printer which is displayed in the system. That's why I tought someone found a way of filtering the printers based on the language, or some attributes, but seems the 420t does not return this attribute.

Comment: Usually, network developers give special printers special printer identifiers.  Like, all Zebra printers have a network identifier that starts with the letter Z.  If only the user knows the network printer identifier for a Zebra printer, then he'll have to tell you his printer is a Zebra printer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Zebra SDK](https://www.zebra.com/de/de/support-downloads/printer-software/link-os-multiplatform-sdk.html) you can make use of the different *Discoverer classes:

- NetworkDiscoverer
- RemoteDiscoverer
- UsbDiscoverer

For example,

```java
for (DiscoveredPrinterDriver discoveredPrinter : UsbDiscoverer.getZebraDriverPrinters()) {
  log.info("Driver USB Printer " + discoveredPrinter);
}
```

Comment: The SDK does not install I get an error:
Flexeraayd$aaa: Windows DLL failed to load
 at Flexeraayd.af(Unknown Source)
 at Flexeraayd.aa(Unknown Source)
 at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.init(Unknown Source).... and more

Comment: I have unzipped the SDK, and I found an archive in InstallerData\Disk1\InstData folder named Resource1.zip . In this archive there are some jar files, one for each platform they say it works this sdk. Seems "PC_zg_ia_sf.jar" is fo Java. I will make some tests with this jar file.